# Running Windows 8 in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04, windows-8, wine

I would like to try Windows 8 on Ubuntu 10.04 in virtualbox ose I have Windows 7 previously installed along with Ubuntu in pc. Now when I started virtual machine I got the error.

[image]

I opened bios utility for checking VT-X and no-execute memory protection. But can't find it. My pc use AMD sempron.

This is what I see in securAble using Wine

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: "This is what I see in securAble using Windows" - That screenshot doesn't show SecurAble running under Windows. Also, if your processor supports it but the feature's turned off in your BIOS, see [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/SysAdmins/OS/Windows/2003Server/you-need-to-have-hardware) for more.

Answer (score 3):

Your system doesn't support hardware virtualization. Windows 8 requires hardware virtualization enabled.

Short of changing your processor, there isn't you can do.

Answer (score 1):

My AMD Sempron 140 *does* have hardware virtualization; however it may work only when the processor has been "unlocked".

Many AMD Sempron single-core chips are actually dual-core chips with the second core and some features (like virtualization) disabled at startup. The system BIOS can easily re-enable the second core along with the other features, and many desktop motherboards which support the AMD Sempron can perform this unlocking. Once unlocked, the processor will identify as an Athlon II X2 and should show virtualization enabled.

Note well that AMD does not advertise support for either virtualization or the second CPU core for Sempron chips, so your particular CPU may not actually have the support.